# How to argue that $X$ is a discrete variable?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable on the probabality space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\varphi_X(t_0) = 1$. Then I have to show that $X$ is discrete.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
    1 = \varphi_X(t_0) = \mathbb{E}[e^{it_0 X}] = \mathbb{E}[\cos(t_0 X)] + i \mathbb{E}[\sin(t_0 X)] = \mathbb{E}[\cos(t_0 X)] 
\end{align*}

Thus since $\cos(t_0X)$ at most can be $1$ then $1 = \cos(t_0X)$ almost sure. However, $1 = \cos(t_0X) \iff Xt_0 \in \{2p \pi \mid p \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Is this enough to conclude that $Xt_0$ is discrete since $Xt_0$ is in a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Thus, since $t_0 \neq 0$, $X = \frac{1}{t_0} t_0 X$ must also be discrete. Is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arrive at the fact that $\operatorname{img}(X)\subset \frac{2\pi}{t_0}\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{t_0}\mathbb{Z}$ is a discrete set, so we are done.

Comment: But what allows the asker to consider that $\mathbb{E}(\sin t_0X)=0$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie if you have $1=a+ib$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ then $1=a$ and $b=0$

Comment: Hi Masacrosco. Thanks for the comment. In the next task I am asked to prove that $X$ is discrete where I now know that $|\varphi_X(t_0)| = 1$. Now by definition there exists $\theta_0 \in (-\pi, \pi]$ such that $\varphi_X(t_0) = e^{-i \theta_0}$. Therefore, $$\varphi_{X + \theta_0/t_0}(t_0) = \mathbb{E}[e^{i t_0 (X + \theta_0 / t_0)}] = \varphi_X(t_0)e^{i \theta_0} = e^{-i \theta_0}e^{i\theta_0} = 1$$, thus $X + \theta_0/t_0$ is discrete from what I just showed. But how do I now conclude that $X$ is discrete?

Comment: @Mathias open a question for this

Comment: @Mascroso Evidently ! Sorry for this silly question.